# Winapi: Child window that is registered and not created gives the parent window it's background color

Tags: c++, winapi

Im trying to create a windows application with winapi. So i want to have one parent window and one child window in it. Here is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
LRESULT CALLBACK ChildProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

const char szChildName[] = "Child window title";
const UINT PM_COLORCHANGED = WM_APP + 1;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    MSG        msg;
    HWND       hWnd;
    WNDCLASS   wc;

    char       szAppName[] = "title";

    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon = NULL;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = (LPCWSTR)szAppName;
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

    RegisterClass(&wc);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(LTGRAY_BRUSH);
    wc.hIcon = NULL;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = ChildProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = (LPCWSTR)szChildName;

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    hWnd = CreateWindow((LPCWSTR)szAppName,
        (LPCWSTR)szAppName,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HWND    hChild;
    static RECT    rect;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
        hChild = CreateWindow((LPCWSTR)szChildName,
            NULL,
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_DLGFRAME,
            5,
            rect.bottom - 35,
            rect.right - 10,
            30,
            hWnd,
            NULL,
            ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance,
            NULL);
        return 0;
    }
    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        return 0;
    }
    case PM_COLORCHANGED:
    {
        return 0;
    }
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        return 0;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
LRESULT CALLBACK ChildProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        
        return 0;
    }
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        
        return 0;
    }
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        
        return 0;
    }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

This works perfect, so i see the child window at the bottom of the application.
But, instead of `WNDCLASS` I want to use `WNDCLASSEX`, which forces me to use `RegisterClassEx()` to register the windows. Also I want to use `CreateWindowEx`, my code looks like that:

```
#include <windows.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
LRESULT CALLBACK ChildProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

const char szChildName[] = "Child name";
const UINT PM_COLORCHANGED = WM_APP + 1;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    MSG        msg;
    HWND       hWnd;
    WNDCLASSEX   wc;

    char       szAppName[] = "The Child Window";

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon = NULL;
    wc.hIconSm = NULL;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = (LPCWSTR)szAppName;
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(LTGRAY_BRUSH);
    wc.hIcon = NULL;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)ChildProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = (LPCWSTR)szChildName;

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
        wc.lpszClassName,
        L"parent window",
        (WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU),
        200,
        150,
        1000,
        1000,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL               
    );

    

    ShowWindow(hWnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HWND    hChild;
    static RECT    rect;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
        hChild = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
           (LPCWSTR)szChildName,
            L"child window",
            (WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_DLGFRAME),
            200,
            150,
            200,
            200,
            hWnd,
            NULL,
            ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance,
            NULL
        );

        return 0;
    }
    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        return 0;
    }
    case PM_COLORCHANGED:
    {
        return 0;
    }
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        return 0;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
LRESULT CALLBACK ChildProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        
        return 0;
    }
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        
        return 0;
    }
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        
        return 0;
    }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

**The problem:** Now i only see the color of the child window, so the whole application has this background color of the child window, so somehow the pc repainted everything in the color of the child window. (no child window is even visible, everything i see is only this LTGRAY_Brush of the child window.

Weird is: If i delete the line where the child window is created, so this line:

```
hChild = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
           (LPCWSTR)szChildName,
            L"child window",
            (WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_DLGFRAME),
            200,
            150,
            200,
            200,
            hWnd,
            NULL,
            ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance,
            NULL
```

then even now, the background color gets the same as the one that i registered the child class with. Altough the child class hasn't been created. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `CreateWindowEx(NULL, wc.lpszClassName, ..._` You are creating the window using the child class name, not the app class name. Whichever name happened to be assigned to `wc.lpszClassName` last.

Comment: Every `(LPCWSTR)` cast in the code is a lie. Remove the casts, and allow the compiler to point out the errors. Then go ahead and fix those errors.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik Omg, i see, thanks. I didn't know that the app class name that is stored in the lpszclassname is there so that the created window knows that the class belongs to it. i thought it was just a name for identification.

Comment: @IInspectable What should i do it for? It doesn't cause errors and the variables will not be changed / can not be changed by anyone except me.

Comment: `(LPCWSTR)szChildName` must not be - remove `(LPCWSTR)`

Comment: How did you imagine `CreateWindow` figured out which window procedure to use?

Comment: I just thought it would use the last that were registered